# Using ^M in a vim -s script

Tags: vim

I'm trying to use a vim script to clean up some subtitle files.

When I paste these commands into vim, they work fine. However the lines with ^M in them aren't working when being used by vim -s script.txt filename.srt.

This is the contents of script.txt (image, because ^M's break things):

[image: script.txt]

Is what I'm trying to do possible? or should I attack it in a different way?

Comment: Is `<CR>` a valid replacement here? Or even `\n`?

Comment: ah, \r was the solution. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to replace the ^M with \r. This works with vim -s.